# Anaconda Prompt failure: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: anaconda

This is my Anaconda prompt.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPWw7.png)
Any command where I use conda gives respone, 'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I tried adding a path environment variable to the scripts folder of my main Anaconda folder. But, it didn't help.
This is also the 2nd time that I have installed Anaconda, the first time it was a bigger mess. Keeping that aside, what should I do now?

Comment: 1. Please verify first Anaconda is installed in your path or not ?
C:\Users\<YourUsername>\Anaconda3 or something similar.
Or type conda --version to verify.

2. You also need to add a couple of paths. Please recheck once.
First one: root directory of the Anaconda installation (As -> C:\Users\<YourUsername>\Anaconda3) and then the scripts directory (Such as C:\Users\<YourUsername>\Anaconda3\Scripts),
After modifying the PATH variable, Please restart the terminal or prompt before proceeding.

If the issue persists, please share the downloaded URL. Error? What Path set?
Thank you

Comment: I have installed Anaconda in my D drive, the reason prompt was starting in C drive was due to the 'Start in' value. I changed it to the location of Anaconda which is D:\Anaconda3. Now it starts in the specified position, I also added the 2 paths to PATH variable like you said. Now the prompt starts in correct location but 'the system cannot find the path specified' still shows on top.

Comment: okay, can you please go to the location of anaconda3/bin, try to open the terminal from there, and then run the command? Try to open the terminal from anaconda3/bin for example /opt/anaconda3/bin. Please try once.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. And no, the prompt still says 'the system cannot find the path specified'. The path variable is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please verify first Anaconda is installed in your path or not. C:\Users<YourUsername>\Anaconda3 or something similar. Or type conda --version to verify.
2. You also need to add a couple of paths. Please recheck once.
   First: the root directory of the Anaconda installation (As -> C:\Users<YourUsername>\Anaconda3) and Second: the scripts directory (Such as C:\Users<YourUsername>\Anaconda3\Scripts), After modifying the PATH variable, Please restart the terminal or prompt before proceeding.
3. Please go to the location of anaconda3/bin, try to open the terminal from there, and then run the command. Sample path in my system: /opt/anaconda3/bin.